# Creating a Cross section of a river

Tags: qgis, flood, hec-ras

I am using QGIS and HEC-RAS for my project. HEC-RAS needs a file for the river bathymetry. Since I do not have data for river bathymetry, I decided to use the **Profile Tool** in QGIS to create a river section. However, the Profile tool only allows to get a single cross section. What I want is the whole stretch of the river. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a terrain model? if yes, then Qgis might help you. Have a look to the RiverGIS plugin

Comment: QGIS will not help you really with assuming the bathymetry, that is better done within HEC-RAS with the channel modification tool